# Confused about type coercion in function calls (stack frames)

Tags: oracle, plsql, coercion, stack-frame

Consider the following example:

```
create or replace function f(n integer) return integer as
begin
  return n;
end;
/

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(f(3.8));
end;
/

3.8


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This makes no sense to me. Obviously, PL/SQL simply ignores the `integer` specification, both on entering the function and on exiting it. Is this simply a bug? Is it a design choice, made deliberately by the language developers?

Here is why I find this confusing. Compare to the following example:

```
declare
  x integer;
begin
  x := 3.8;
  dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
/

4


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In this example, the data type specification is complied with. PL/SQL doesn't throw an error, but at least it performs an implicit coercion and it does not violate the data type declared for `x` - the variable stores the value 4, an integer, not 3.8.

So, how does PL/SQL do the function call thing in the first example? As far as I understand (never having been trained formally in computing), whenever the compiler or interpreter finds a function call it creates a stack frame, with variables for the arguments passed to the function and for the return value to come back from the function. Aren't these variables, when the stack frame is created, supposed to be **the same data type** as specified in the function declaration? If the stack frame has a field of `integer` data type for the argument 3.8, how come that is not coerced to 4 before it is even stored in the corresponding variable? And the same thing for the return value: if the function returns 3.8 but the caller expects an integer (and therefore the corresponding variable in the stack frame should be `integer`), how is it able to accept the return value 3.8?

And, most disturbing - why is this behavior different from the behavior when explicitly declared variables are involved (as in my second example)?

Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is found in the documentation for Oracle Database (to which your question has absolutely no relation whatsoever).

Firstly, `INTEGER` in the said database is a [synonym for `NUMBER(38)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF). Upon assignment to a `NUMBER(38)` variable `x`, as in your second example, according to the assignment rules the `NUMBER` (with arbitrary precision) literal `3.8` is rounded.

In your first example though no assignment happens because `IN` parameters to PL/SQL subprograms [are passed by reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-518B8827-26CC-4734-B799-ACB038185638__BCFHBGBI) and the same reference (to the `NUMBER` value 3.8) is returned.

Comment: OK - excellent point about the fact that `IN` parameters are passed by reference. This explains how the value 3.8 gets passed to the function. I don't believe, though, that this explains the behavior of the `return` step. The function returns a value which may have nothing to do with the variable passed in; why is it allowed to return a non-integer, and how is that possible?

Comment: And, to clarify further: If I change the definition of the function, changing the `return` clause to `return 3.8` (a hard-coded constant), the function will return 4. Why does it return 3.8 when I write `return n` and `n` is 3.8?

Comment: On further thought and with additional experimentation, I am still not 100% clear on the inputs either. If I change the function to `return varchar2` and the return value is `return n`, if I call `f('000100')` the output is `'100'`, not `'000100'`. Which means that somewhere the argument was indeed converted to number and back - the function didn't simply return the input value. "Passing by reference" clearly doesn't ***really*** mean "passing by reference" when the input has different data type than the function expects.

Comment: Perfect example of why you should **never relay on *implicit* data conversion**. If a variable should contain data type T then make the assigned variable data type T, If necessary use an explicit conversion.

Comment: @Belayer - No doubt. My preference would be for an error to be thrown whenever a value of the wrong type is passed to a function (or assigned to a variable), instead of Big Brother attempting implicit conversions behind my back. But I have no control over what users do with my functions. I posted a related (but different) question on OTN: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4479941/strong-er-data-typing-in-pl-sql-how#latest